# Call to a member function on a non-object eloquent attach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having an issue with laravel not seeing my tags() method for attaching new tags on a new entry. I keep getting Call to a member function on a non-object when I try to run the method and attach tags to my Tile model. All methods are returning their relations. I followed the same order as the documentation says eloquent.

Controller

```
      $tile = \Tiles\Tile::find($tile_id);
      $tile->tags()->attach($tag_array);
```

Model

```
<?php namespace Tiles;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tile extends Model {

    /**
     * The Tile table
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tiles';

    /**
     * Pivot table for tags
     * @var string
     */
    protected $pivot = 'tag_tile';


    /**
     *  Get the tags associated with the given tile
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
   public function tags() {

        return $this->belongsToMany('Tiles\Tag', $this->pivot, 'tile_id', 'tag_id')->withTimestamps();

    }

}
```

Comment: I think **\Tiles\Tile::find($tile_id);**  is return null. **$tile_id** record is existing on table. please check it ?

Comment: @JayDhameliya Hi! I checked the db and also did a dump with the input and $tile_id var is not null and returning the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. I figured out the solution. I created a method in my model and pushed each to an array and fed it to the attach method. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

**Model**

```
public function tags() {

        return $this->belongsToMany('Tiles\Tag', $this->pivot, 'tag_id', 'tile_id')->withTimestamps();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I still get Call to a member function tags() on a non-object